# How to use the same nested router-outlet among multiple modules?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I would like to share the side-nav routes among multiple modules, for example the route "/admin" so i could have something like this:

```
 "admin/side-nav-children(all_side_nav_routes)".
```

Everything works fine but my admin module is not loading the router outlet related to the nav-bar and not even detecting the child routes.

I already have one router outlet in my application which is the one that is loading the admin module, that router-outlet is located in app.component.html.

[image]

**app-routing.module.ts routes**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './core/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
      { path: 'cashin', loadChildren: './core/cashin/cashin.module#CashinModule' },
      { path: 'cashout', loadChildren: './core/cashout/cashout.module#CashoutModule' },
      { path: 'finantial', loadChildren: './core/finantial/finantial.module#FinantialModule' },
      { path: 'support', loadChildren: './core/support/support.module#SupportModule' }
    ]
  }
];
```

**admin-routes.ts routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: sideNavRoutes
}
];
```

**side-nav.routes.ts**

```
export const sideNavRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: SideNavComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '' , redirectTo: 'start', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'start', component: StartComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
    { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
    { path: 'sessions', component: SessionsComponent },
    { path: 'transactions', component: TransactionsComponent },
    { path: 'options', component: OptionsComponent },
    { path: 'income', component: IncomeComponent },
    { path: 'expenses', component: ExpensesComponent },
    { path: 'commissions', component: CommissionsComponent }
  ]
}
]
```

this is my side-nav template for now:

**side-nav.component.html**

```
    <router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet> 
    <h1>SIDE NAV</h1>
```

and my admin template

**admin.component.html**

```
<h1>Admin</h1>
<side-nav></side-nav>
```

Comment: So you want to use <side-nav></side-nav> everywhere ?

Comment: yes and use the routes defined in that side nav as child routes,, eventually i'd like to do that in multiple modules but for now i'm trying to get it to work only in admin module, see how i try to set the children to the side-nav routes in admin-routes.ts.